# Weird behavior with bar buttons not showing in Xcode IDE but display behind back button at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm very new to Xcode and Swift and I'm cramming as much information as I can in order to complete this project quickly. I created a view controller that contains 3 bar buttons at the top. After I created a segue to open this view controller, the bar buttons all disappeared in the IDE. The buttons do show up at runtime but they are inaccessible as they appear to be behind the layer that displays the back button.

How can I delete these buttons from my view controller if they aren't showing up at design time in the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete them, look in your 'View Controller Scene' tab.  You can find that by clicking the little square icon in the lower left-hand corner of your main storyboard view.  This will show a hierarchy of all the elements in the interface builder.  Click and delete.

If they aren't showing up in the view controller scene tab, then I don't know how they could be showing up in the simulator.